# ktlint disable standard rules

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, ktlint

I have **.editorConfig** file in project directory, where I do disable several rules but it seem that configuration is ignored

file content:

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*.{kt,kts}]
ktlint_standard_no-wildcard-imports = disabled
ktlint_standard_package-name = disabled
```

using :

```
  id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.6.1"
```

when I run ktlintCheck still getting errors for those two rules, see report lines :

```
<error line="1" column="1" severity="error" message="Package name must not contain underscore" source="package-name" />

 <error line="20" column="1" severity="error" message="Wildcard import" source="no-wildcard-imports" />
```

any ideas?

Comment: hm, it seems those works for latest versions - 12.0.3